# how to call previous activity in android?

Tags: android-activity

I have five activity in my app,
Act1->Act2->Act3->Act4->Act5,

All activity goes in single direction as I have stated above,
 Now I have to call again Act2 after successful completion of my Act5's task, so its working good and showing me the Act2 (I have Used `startActivity(callIntent)` in Act5 for showing me Act2 again), 
 After this when I click on Back button in Act2, I have Act1 (I have Used `startActivity(callIntent)` in Act2 for showing me Act1 again) its what I want ..... 
But the problem is that when I click Act1's back button it is going to put me on Act2. But I want to exit from there, because Act1 is the first initial activity.

How Can I set focus to my hidden activity , instead of creating Intent and call startActivity.

Any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I got pretty much understanding of "back stack" for all the activities in an app.

Each time I moved to another activity and also for opening previous activity I have used `Intent.startActivity()` with `flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, So every time I have new activity added in the "back-stack".

I have tried intent flag as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` while calling previous activity from "back-stack" using `Intent.startActivity()` and I got the solution of calling back the previous activity and clears all stack top activity above the calling one activity. So now back button does working nice as I needed.

Let see My problem of calling previous activity ,
`A = activity; A1->A2->A3->A4->A5->B2` ,  now if you click on back button you will have A1 activity , and after clicking on A1's back button you have again B2 activity which was called after A5 and so on.

After using the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in A5 activity and called again A2 (Not creating new activity but calling precious one) I have following situation.

```
A = activity; A1->A2->A3->A4->A5
```

calling previous A2 activity, and I have following scenario.
`A1->A2` only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following code (with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
callIntent.setClass(CurrentActivity.this,PreviousActivity.class);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Try using following one with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
callIntent.setClass(CurrentActivity.this,PreviousActivity.class);
startActivity(callIntent);
```